# Wamp server is green, but localhost shows webpage not available??

Tags: wampserver

Wamp server is green, but localhost shows webpage not available

Changed port to 81 but still not loading.

Hosts file looks ok too.

Any ideas what might be the issue

Comment: what URL you are using in browser?

Comment: I am browsing http://localhost

Comment: If you have set 81 port, then you need to browse http://localhost:81/

Comment: If wampmanager icon is green, then port 80 is fine. What version of WAMPServer are you running? What version of Apache are you running? What is in the HOSTS file? What is in the `httpd.conf` file in the section starting with `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">`

Answer (score 0):

i thing it start on another port although check [apache access log] for more detail on which port it actually starting.or add your log